# Конструкторы производного класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Общий класс:

```
class Counter {
protected:
    unsigned int count;
public:
    Counter(): count(0) {}
    Counter(int c): count(c) {}
    int get_count() { return count; }
    Counter operator++() { return Counter(++count); }
};
```

Потомок, версия 1:

```
class CountDn: public Counter
{
public:
    Counter operator--() { return Counter(--count); }
};
```

Потомок, версия 2:

```
class CountDn: public Counter
{
public:
    CountDn(): Counter() {}
    CountDn(int c): Counter(c) {}
    CountDn operator--() { return CountDn(--count); }
};
```

Скажите, пожалуйста. Почему в первой версии подкласса нельзя вернуть декремент класса **CountDn**? Всё равно ведь используется конструктор общего класса?

Я ссылаюсь на книгу Р.Лафоре "ООП в С++" - стр. 364, пункт "Определение производного класса": "*... в то же время CountDn наследует все возможности класса Counter: конструктор и методы*"

P.S. Может читаю устаревшую литературу?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Вот код - https://ideone.com/K0Qewj - что в нем не так, как хотите вы?

Comment: в целом есть стандарт, который говорит, что operator-- должен возвращать **ссылку** на тип такой же, как и сам this

Comment: @KoVadim Разве стандарт запрещает переопределять операторы инкремента-декремента, как вздумается? Да, по-хорошему, желательно не уходить от семантики стандартного оператора, но вроде же не запрещено?...

Comment: потому,что в `CountDn` нет конструктора от `CountDn(unsigned int);` Конструкторы у потомков **не** наследуются.

Comment: А разве конструкторы не наследуются?

Comment: @AlexGlebe а где прочесть о наследовании конструкторов можно? В книге написано - Р. Лафоре "ООП в С++", стр. 364, пункт "Определение производного класса": ... в то же время CountDn наследует все возможности класса Counter: конструктор и методы

Comment: @Harry - на самом деле программист может делать все, что он захочет. А вот будет оно работать или нет, это уже компилятор решит.

Comment: Если бы простые функции можно было наследовать **и** создавать со своими аргументами, то было-бы полная неразбериха какая функция выполниться своя или предка. С конструкторами та-же беда.   https://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting

Comment: @AlexGlebe укажите ответ, я отмечу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой перевод от [Страуструпа](https://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting) :

### Унаследованные конструкторы

Люди иногда путаются в том, что обычные правила области применимы к членам класса. В частности, член базового класса не находится в той же области, что и член производного класса:

```
struct B {
    void f(double);
};

struct D : B {
    void f(int);
};

B b;   b.f(4.5);    // хорошо
D d;   d.f(4.5);    // сюрприз: вызывает f (int) с аргументом 4
```

В C++98, мы можем "поднять" набор перегруженных функций из базового класса в производный класс:

```
struct B {
    void f(double);
};

struct D : B {
    using B::f;     // приведите все f()-ки из B в область видимости
    void f(int);    // добавьте новую f()
};

B b;   b.f(4.5);    // хорошо
D d;   d.f(4.5);    // хорошо: вызывает D::f (double) , который является B::f(double)
```

Я уже говорил, что "Немногим больше, чем историческая случайность, мешает использовать это для работы как для конструктора, так и для обычной функции-члена." C++11 обеспечивает это средство:

```
class Derived : public Base { 
public: 
    using Base::f;    // поднять базовые f в область действия производного - работает в C++98
    void f(char);     // обеспечить новый f
    void f(int);      // этот f предпочтительнее Base::f(int) 

    using Base::Base; // поднять базовые конструкторы производной области -- только в C++11
    Derived(char);    // предоставить новый конструктор
    Derived(int);     // предпочтите этот конструктор против Base::Base(int) 
    // ...
};
```

Если вы так решите, вы все равно можете выстрелить себе в ногу, унаследовав конструкторы в производном классе, в котором вы определяете новые переменные-члены, нуждающиеся в инициализации:

```
struct B1 {
    B1(int) { }
};

struct D1 : B1 {
    using B1::B1; // неявно объявляет D1(int)
    int x;
};

void test()
{
    D1 d(6);    // Упс: d. x не инициализируется
    D1 e;       // ошибка: D1 не имеет конструктора по умолчанию
}
```

Вы можете удалить пулю из вашей ноги с помощью члена-инициализатора:

```
    struct D1 : B1 {
        using B1::B1;   // неявно объявляет D1(int)
        int x{0};   // Примечание: x инициализируется
    };

    void test()
    {
        D1 d(6);    // d. x равно нулю
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

С чего вы взяли, что нельзя? Проверьте:

```
CountDn c;    
cout << (--c).get_count();
```

Для создания объекта `с`, создается объект `Counter` конструктором по умолчанию(первым вызывается этот конструктор), так как не указано как будет конструироваться базовый объект. А значит  поле `count` для объекта `с` будет иметь нулевое значение. Так как он имеет тип `unsigned`, то его декремент не  будет иметь определенного результата, поскольку **никакое отрицательное число не может быть закодировано по типу unsigned int**. А значит  `(--c)` просто будет не уместным действием(какое значение передается в конструктор Counter, что вы хотите вернуть?...), пока вы не увеличили значение  `count` каким то образом.

Comment: Нет, суть в том, что, пока в классе CountDn не будет указан конструктор, принимающий аргумент (и, в свою очередь, перенаправляющий общему конструктору данный аргумент) - вызов декремента для объекта класса CountDn будет бесполезным, а точнее - ошибочным. Во втором случае конструкторы указаны - поэтому декремент объекта класса CountDn работает.

Comment: То есть - конструкторы, получается, не наследуются потомками.

Comment: Нет, суть в том, что вы ничего не поняли и не хотите понимать, слушаете тех, которые также имеют ошибочные  представления. Для чего наследовать конструктор? Потомок  в своей основе имеет уже сконструированный объект базового класса, конструктором по умолчании или тем, который вы укажете в списке инициализации конструктора  потомка.